# How to read and write the same text file in Parallelization using ParallelTable?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, parallelization

I want to know how to write and read a same text file (for example, external.txt ) without conflicts in parallelization. The following is just a small idea, but the problem is there seems a conflicts in writing to the same text file -- ObtainedData sometimes are only part written in the external.txt.

The following is the code just for describe the idea.

```
......

ParallelTable[
 data = Import["external.txt"];
 ExternalMemory = ImportString[data, "List"];

(*get data from some operations, here i ignore the codes using ...... *)
 .....
 .....

(*check whether the ObtainedData is in the external file, if yes skip, 
 if not then write to the file and also write to corresponding results file.*)

If[MemberQ[ExternalMemory,ObtainedData]==False , 

 WriteLine[currentdirectory<>"\\"<>"external.txt", ToString[ObtainedData]];
 WriteLine[currentdirectory<>"\\"<>"results"<>ToString[$KernelID]<>".txt", ObtainedData];
 ];  

 ,{iilsts, 1, 1000}];

......
```

One thing I thought is to use ***the master (KernelID=0)*** or ***one of other Kernels*** to read all the results files and write to external.txt, but I'm not sure how and whether it can solve.

Is anybody familiar with such problems or similar cases? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Trying to have multiple programs writing in the same file without coordination seems to be calling for problems. What about a [database](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DatabaseConnectivity.html)? If not, depending on the overheads, how frequent the queries and heavy the data you can use [`SetSharedVariable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedVariable.html) to keep a light index synchronized on all kernels.

Comment: I'm not sure how frequent the queries. What do you mean use `SetSharedVariable` to keep a light index? do you mean on all kernels I try to fix the index? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you read the docs for `SetSharedVariable`?  It *"declares symbols as shared variables whose values are synchronized among all parallel kernels."*. If there is a lightweight way to identify your data, you can keep an index in a shared variable or a database instead of searching and writing a file each time. And then create one data file per kernel, so there no possibility of collision.

Comment: I just read the docs for `SetShareVariable`. The way I do is always to write and read the file, I don't know to the lightweight way to identify data yet. I will have a try. Thank you!

Comment: Probably the best answer is that you just shouldn't. Think twice if you really need to do this, and then think again. If you still want it after that, create a separate function for writing to the file and use `SetSharedFunction` on it. There's also `CriticalSection`.

Comment: @XuemeiGu  I'm afraid that unless you provide further information, this question is not answerable  in a specific way. Broad questions are [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD) so your question may put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD). To avoid or revert the Hold you can [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, well-structured and easy to understand. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed, we do want to help. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).